# Convert iptables to Brocade/Vyatta

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, vyatta

I would like to switch from `iptables` to `Brocade/Vyatta`, but are having trouble with "converting" firewall rules.

This is my iptables, which works:

```
# Default policy to drop 'everything' but our output to internet
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P INPUT   DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT  ACCEPT

# Allow established connections (the responses to our outgoing traffic)
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow local programs that use loopback (Unix sockets)
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic between VLAN servers
iptables -A INPUT -s 89.55.42.0/28 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP for monitoring
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

And this is my try on Brocade/Vyatta:

```
set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN default-action 'drop'

set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 10 action 'accept'
set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 10 source address '89.55.42.0/28'

set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 20 action 'accept'
set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 20 destination port '22'
set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 20 protocol 'tcp'

set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 30 action 'accept'
set security firewall name VLAN-200-IN rule 30 protocol 'icmp'

set security firewall name VLAN-200-OUT default-action 'accept'
```

Which is attached to my VLAN/VIF:

```
 interfaces {
        bonding dp0bond1 {
                address 77.51.23.1/23
                mode lacp
                vif 200 {
                        address 89.55.42.0/28
                        firewall {
                            in VLAN-200-IN
                            out VLAN-200-OUT
                        }
                }
                vrrp {
                        vrrp-group 2 {
                                ...
                        }
                }
        }
...
```

I'm testing and want to protect the VLAN 200, but with my example I'm still able to send packets via SIP port 5060 through to servers behind the gateway. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I don't know these Vyatta boxes, but if we assume the VIF configuration is similar in behaviour to an SVI (Vlan interface) on a Cisco router then the in and out directions of the rules should be considered from the router's VLAN interface's perspective not the VLAN itself.

In other words, *IN* is for traffic **entering the router**  on this VLAN, *OUT* is for traffic **leaving the router** on this VLAN. The IN rules protect the rest of your routed network from stuff *on* the vif 200 interface. The OUT rules protect stuff on the vif 200 interface from the rest of your network.

Now you should see that with your very-permissive VLAN-200-OUT policy, you are allowing anything to be routed out the vif 200 interface towards your servers. Since the SIP traffic on 5060 is likely UDP, it doesn't need a two-way TCP connection setup (that might be caught by the IN rules) and is instead allowed to pass.

Of course I may be wrong about this particular platform - and it's not entirely obvious what your actual network topology is. Presumably the Vyatta box is acting as a router?